# MODX REVO как убрать редирект на /404 с несуществующих страниц?

Tags: php, apache, cms, modx

Сейчас при открытии *site.com/sdfsdfsdf* происходит редирект на site.com/404/ и отображается error_page.
Как убрать этот редирект и оставить URL прежним (*/sdfsdfsdf*) , но при этом отображать *error_page* шаблон.

В .htaccess никаких правил не нашёл:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# http -> https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/r.php
RewriteRule .* https://domain.ru%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Rewrite www.domain.com -> domain.com -- used with SEO Strict URLs plugin
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.ru [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/robots.txt$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ r.php [L,QSA]

# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

В системных настройках сайта указан верный ID ресурса *error_page*

Comment: "оставить URL прежним (/sdfsdfsdf) , но при этом отображать error_page шаблон." Это как?

Comment: Случайно нет никаких плагинов типа Redirector? включены ли "дружественные URL"?

Comment: @Tunker , да, установлен Redirector, но правил для 404 там не прописано.

Comment: @ВладимирМалахов , На странице error_page задан текст, который необходимо отображать на странице с 404 status code. Страница /asfasfasf - должна НЕ редиректить на /404/, а просто отдавать 404 статус и отображать текст, прописанный в error_page

Comment: @theblackpost попробуйте отключить Redirector, вот похожая проблема: https://modx.pro/help/3282, у вас Redirector при заходе на несуществующую страницу делает редирект на страницу 404, проверьте в браузере, скорее всего там будет 301 редирект и возврат с кодом 200 страницы 404

Comment: @Tunker да конечно уже пробовал, не помогает.. А в браузере идёт 301 на /404/ а там статус 404.

Comment: А не может быть связано с расширением SEO Strict URLs? я увидел в вашем .htaccess строчки про него, посмотрел на modx.com/extras там в теле скрипта есть строки которые генерируют редирект 301

Comment: @Tunker , разобрались. Выложил решение ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, проблема оказалась в TrailingSlash плагине. Он некорректно обрабатывает несуществующий URL, если в нём нет слэша на конце, перекидывая пользователя на ресурс 37 (который как раз и есть страница 404 в настройках).
Модифицировали плагин, добавив в него проверку на 404